# Making a multidimensional hash, (currently gives empty hash)

Tags: ruby, hash, multidimensional-array, hashmap, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a multidimensional hash with little success.

I have put the script I am using below (note: I am using the bio gem.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bio'

def make_hash(input_file)
  input_read = Hash.new
  biofastafile = Bio::FlatFile.open(Bio::FastaFormat, input_file) 
  biofastafile.each_entry do |entry|
    #### If I uncomment the below line, it gives me 2D hash ###
    ####   input_read[entry.definition] = entry.aaseq
    ####
    input_read.map { |maps|
      id_start, id_end = entry.definition.split('-')
      signalp, seq_end = entry.aaseq.split('-')

     {
       :id_start => id_start,
       :id_end => id_end,
       :signalp => signalp,
       :seq_end => seq_end,
       } 
     }
    end
    return input_read
  end

hash = make_hash("./sample.txt")

puts hash
# puts hash[:id_start]
```

Sample.txt

```
>isotig00003_f6_8 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 11:12
MMHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
>isotig00003_f6_9 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 10:11
MHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
>isotig00004_f6_8 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 11:12
MMHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
>isotig00004_f6_9 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 10:11
MHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
>isotig00009_f2_3 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 22:23
MLKCFSIIMGLILLLEIGGGCA-IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNCSGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD
>isotig00009_f3_9 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 16:17
MKTGIIIFISTVVVLP-ITLKPCGVPFSCCIPDQASGVANTQCGYGVRSPEQQNTFHTKIYTTGCADMFTMWINRYLYYIAGIAGVIVLVELFGFCFAHSLINDIKRQKARWAHR
```

What I want to do is split the sample.txt into entries (every 2 lines). I then want to split each entry into the specific parts e.g.

```
>isotig00003_f6_8 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 11:12
MMHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
```

is made of the

```
definition -->        >isotig00003_f6_8 - Signal P Cleavage Site => 11:12
sequence (aaseq) -->  MMHLLCIVLLL-KWWLLL
```

I then want to split the definition into:

```
:id_start -->   >isotig00003_f6_8
:id_end -->     Signal P Cleavage Site => 11:12
```

and split the sequence (aaseq) into:

```
:signalp -->    MMHLLCIVLLL
:seq_end -->    KWWLLL
```

What I want is to be able to use each of the specific variables (:id_start, :id_end, :signalp, :seq_end) in other methods.

Many Thanks for all help

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your hash should look like at the end.  Also, what is input_read.map supposed to accomplish?  input_read isn't being populated anywhere, so that won't do anything, and you're also not saving the return value from it.

Comment: A lot of this has been covered previously in "[Use SLIM/HAML etc. in a Ruby script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19564803/128421)". Please point to your previous (mostly duplicated) question so people don't keep rehashing, and reanswering with different solutions.

Comment: Sorry for the repeat, I thought I was asking a related but a different question. I have tried to make the answer provided with the previous question to work with the bioruby gem fir quite a few days but I couldn't get it to work. I also looked online for multidimensional hashes but I got nothing. The answer below has been useful. I'll try to use it to get the script to work...

Comment: Hey, I updated the answer to use `each_slice` to iterate through the array in a neater way. I knew there was something that did what I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you. This will generate an array containing hashes; I hope that's what you're after.

```
lines = File.read('sample.txt').split "\n" # You can get your lines however you want.

# Step through the lines in pairs...
lines.each_slice(2).map do |definition, sequence|
  # Create a hash of the split and stripped data.
  Hash[[[:id_start, :id_end], definition.split('-').map(&:strip)].transpose].merge \
  Hash[[[:signalp, :seq_end], sequence.split('-').map(&:strip)].transpose]
end
```

If you want to have these hashes available on some key in a larger hash, you can do this:

```
Hash[lines.each_slice(2).map do |definition, sequence|
       ['WHATEVER YOUR KEY IS GOES HERE', 
        Hash[[[:id_start, :id_end], definition.split('-').map(&:strip)].transpose].merge(
        Hash[[[:signalp, :seq_end], sequence.split('-').map(&:strip)].transpose]
       )]
     end]
```

(I don't get what your key would be here, but you should be able to work with this.)